# Do users log-out?

Tags: user-behavior, logout

We have grown noticeably accustomed to logging in or signing in to systems and websites in many places.

I know that many sites such as my bank ([NetBank](https://www.my.commbank.com.au/netbank/Logon/Logon.aspx)) logs me out as soon as I exit the page<sup>1</sup>; but many and more don't.

In an [article which I recently read](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/more_api_security_choices_oauth_ssl_saml_and_rolling_your_own), the writer states:

> This type of authentication maps very naturally to a web site, because users are used to “logging in” when they start working with a particular site and “logging out” when they are done.

But is this actually the case? **Do users explicitly log out of sites when they are done?**

I know *I* certainly don't; and I'm a Web/Software Developer<sup>2</sup>

---

**NOTES:**

- Please provide evidence and/or research as part of your answers (if possible).
- I ask this as I would like to know whether or not to base my UX design on users' behaviour to ensure their safety.
- Question is not relevant to non-safety-concerned sites where it doesn't matter if you stay logged in (StackExchange on home computer etc.).
- According to [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/3630/4430) on a similar question; many sites don't even prominently display the log-out/sign-out button.
- Another related question: [How should a user exit an intranet web app with automatic login?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46102/how-should-a-user-exit-an-intranet-web-app-with-automatic-login)

<sup>1. I think that it doesn't kill the session when I leave, but kills any sessions if they exist when I return, making it seem like it kills on page close. Either way, doesn't matter for our discussion.</sup>

<sup>2. *Unless* I'm at a public or work computer.</sup>

Comment: Could also be worth considering the environment the user is likely to access the site from. I know my log out behaviour is differs on my home computer from my work computer and again from a public computer.

Comment: May be not directly relevant, but when user want to switch account, normally they will need to logout and login with another username.

Comment: I do. Not from all sites, but most certainly from all security sensitive sites and from all sites that otherwise use all kinds of scripts to collect information about me. Not that it would actually prevent them from still keeping the cookie and only making me believe I have thwarted them,  but I sure as heck will try and make it as difficult for them as possible.

Comment: Your bank may also expire sessions by time since last activity. I've walked away from mine many times, and come back after a remarkably short time to find it has timed out.

Comment: Don't think this is answer worthy, as it has no research. However, from my experience, they do not log out for a few main reasons. Most normal users are not really aware of the security risks, and just think "it won't happen to me, so they stay logged in". Also, its more convenient to stay logged in IMO

Comment: @GeorgeH I agree with that. I do the same thing.

Comment: @BorhanMooz, I'll confess, so do I!

Comment: FYI, most web sites use HTTP cookies for authentication, and set them to expire automatically after a certain time or when browser exits. I bet your bank sets its cookies to expire in ca. 15 minutes, and renews it on each page refresh or via AJAX. After the cookie expires, the browser will stop sending it to the server but keep it on hard drive until garbage cookies are collected, typically when there are >3000 cookies.

Comment: This question cannot be answered the way it is structured, as it is merely a Yes/No poll type question. I am voting to close it until it is reworded so that it can be answered objectively.

Comment: My college website tries to log me out every 20 minutes regardless of me being active or not. It just pops up asking if I want to be logged out, which is annoying.  Hello, if I'm active on the site, I probably don't want to be logged out automatically. The other time I was away for a few hours, and I came back and saw the prompt there. It had already logged me off, but it was bad UX. Doesn't make to show up a popup on active or inactive.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Users do log out conceptually - but not explicitly.

Users have become conditioned to sites managing security on their behalf by automatically logging sessions out. They know this because they are continually having to re-login.  As this has become expected behaviour, in their mind leaving a site is 'fine' and log-out 'will happen'.

But actually this "Log-In" / "Log-Out " dichotomy is artificial.  Amazon manages this very well in three levels:

- Unknown user
- Known user => access non-sensitive actions
- Known user recently re-authenticated => access sensitive actions

Comment: I can't +1 this. I do actively and explicitly log out. Not downvoting either because I realize that many users are not as aware of the pitfalls of staying ("partly") logged in.

Comment: @MarjanVenema The question for me is "what is the most common behaviour for unsophisticated users", anecdata from anyone sufficiently competent to have a stack exchange account are just line noise when it comes to planning UX work.

Comment: @Racheet: Hmm, so I am just line noise? No problem, but you may want to rethink that. I am absolutely not the only one who is very alert when it comes to my privacy.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I didn't mean it in a perjorative sense. Sorry if I came across as rude. What I meant to say was that when designing for user experience, it's always best to design a workflow for the user-model of the user you have the most of. Unless you're fog creek software, that user is going to be _much_ less sophisticated than anyone with a stack exchange profile.

Comment: @MarjanVenema In other words: You are the 1%. You'll be able to work out the log-in behaviour of any given web-site with little difficulty. People designing the log-in behaviour need to be thinking about how to make it understandable for everybody else. That's the whole point of UX work. Making interfaces that are usable by people that aren't as smart as us.

Comment: @Racheet: don't worry, I didn't take it personally. I forget to insert smiley's sometimes. Of course you design for the majority. I guess I just don't want the traits of "unsophisticated users" to lead to the logout link being buried in obscurity, or worse: deemed unnecessary. A missing or hidden logout link would leave me wondering whether the site will actually log me out on a time-out as there are also sites that keep you logged in indefinitely unless you log out explicitly.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Hey, I logout too!  The best way I have seen it put was by Alan Cooper: What percentage of Americans drive manual or stick-shift cars? About 5%.  But informal survey of  software engineers about 75% of them drive stick shift.  As a cohort they *like* control and *understand* the ramifications.

Comment: @Jayfang: Yup, there are always subgroups where the percentages differ hugely from the general "norm".

Answer (score 124):

Do note that, even if users "expect" most sites to log them out automatically, in certain circumstances (eg. a shared computer at a friend's home/library/Internet café), they will need an explicit "log out" link to assure them their session is terminated and no one else can access their account.

Another valid use case is when users have multiple accounts (husband and wife) and want to switch accounts.

So please **always provide an explicit option to "log out"**.

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to access via public computers.

Comment: Agree completely. My "implicit logout behaviour" answer was in no ways meant to condone the practise, or suggest that "Log Out" UI was unimportant.

Comment: +1 I couldn't begin to tell you how many times I've gone to check my email only to be realize my wife's account is the one signed in.

Comment: While this does provide a good answer as to *Why* sites should allow users to explicitly log out, it doesn't answer or even address the OP's actual question of *Do users log out*.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: absolutely. I don't have any evidence and/or research about hard numbers if users log out, so I don't post it. Other answers here do, feel free to upvote those, it's a free market. My answer states that it's not really important if everyone does it or just 10%, it mentions two very important use cases where **both from a usability perspective and a security perspective, the possibility to log out should always be provided**.

Comment: @Konerak -I don't see where your answer states `it's not really important if everyone does it or just 10%`. Regardless, I'm not disagreeing with the facts your answer provides.  I'm just saying that they don't answer the question that the OP asked.  You are answering the question the OP *should have asked*. Now, I can't really fault you for that because the OP asked a Yes/No question which is why I didn't down vote you.  I just think that something should be said in your answer about why you aren't answering the question the OP asked.

Comment: When I'm at a friend's I log in in an incognito window, so that I don't have to log them out of anything. Then i close the incognito window when I'm done. Voila!

Comment: I agree with @CodeMaverick; in that as a Programmer/Web Developer, I already *know* that users **should** log-out, and a log-out button must be provided, but I'm just wondering what their behaviour is.

Comment: I'm facing this debate at work. Our non technical staff believes, quite strongly, that they've logged out once the browser has been closed and that it is a bug that the session could ever be remembered. However, [Chrome and Firefox](http://blog.petersondave.com/cookies/Session-Cookies-in-Chrome-Firefox-and-Sitecore/) can reinstate session cookies and sessionStorage when tabs are re-opened from history or as a result of a crash.

Comment: When "personal" computers started getting shared between strangers (e.g. web kiosks, internet cafes) logout (to clear data and end sessions) became essential. For a home computer, multiple accounts can be setup at the OS level and provides a BETTER overall approach. For Mobile apps, modern smartphone OSs provide multiple/guest accounts again a far BETTER approach than logging out all the time. Especially on mobile logout is costly because it will typically sever push-messaging communication channel and necessitate re-download of all data on potentially costly networks which also costs battery.

Comment: And for the "my device is about to be stolen therefore I logout all the time approach", you are going to win lottery this week so you should also buy all the tickets you can, right? Find my Device and Remote Wipe features are the controls that will save you when your phone is lost/stolen, not logging out of an app.

Answer (score 18):

I have a web site that offers various  services for weddings, so my target audience has pretty diversified technical skills. My unequivocal conclusion after 2 years running the site is **users do not log out**.

Or they just leave a page open, and then I am logging them out after 10 idle minutes, or (much worse scenario) they just close the tab/the browser with the close button (x).

And then I have to track these "hung" sessions for some time, to make sure that the user is really gone.  What a headache! Sometimes I think that the user is gone , but s/he actually is there, just does nothing. Sometimes a user is gone, but I am still thinking that s/he is there, so I prevent opening this account on another computer. An absolute nightmare, but I believe it is a sad reality for any non professional audience - **closing by x, no log outs**

As I base my conclusion on thousands' users experience, I think this generalization is well substantiated.

Comment: Why not let them log in from 2 different devices? It's pretty common for me to look at something on my phone or tablet, then decide I want to look at it on the computer. I may need to stay logged in on the phone/tablet to see the address as I'm typing it on the computer. I certainly don't expect to be logged out on one of the devices when I log in on the other one.

Comment: Well, as I do not have Google power behind me, I cannot afford developing Google Docs like system that allows simultaneous  editing of a document by multiple users. If you are aware of any 3rd party open source solution to this problem, I will be really grateful.

Comment: @Flot2011 Just log out the previous session whenever someone else uses the same account on a different device.

Comment: @Flot2011 http://socket.io/ If you want to write a real-time app you could check this out. There are also some Javascript frameworks that wrap this functionality, such as Meteor and Derby, but they are not production-ready.

Comment: If you deal with credit cards (e.g. for ecommerce transactions), then PCI-DSS mandates that your sessions expire. Short of compliance frameworks breathing down your neck, you probably have obligations re: privacy legisliation. If there is private information that could be leaked/breached by not expiring sessions/providing logout then one could say you're negligent.

Answer (score 11):

As has been noted above, this depends on the app. But even before the app, this depends on the user. Advanced users adapt their behavior to the specific app, based on a balance between the app's sensitivity and their own <s>paranoia</s> security awareness, like @Goodwine described.

Beginners do not log out. I've spoken to a number of not very computer-savvy people in theirs sixties who were at a complete loss when they tried logging into their email account from somebody else's computer and it had asked them for their password. As they usually put it, "this computer doesn't have my email". They had forgotten that they even had a password, and the concept of logging in was foreign to them. This because they never log out at home, they know that they have to click a bookmark in their browser ("in The Internet") and their email is there waiting for them. This goes for often-used apps, like email.

In more rarely-used apps, like online banking, they are well aware of the concept of logging in, because the app takes care to log them out after a period of inactivity or when they close their browser. But they still don't log out - they're both uneducated about information security, and they aren't aware that there's a "session" going on. When they're done they just close the browser, because they're done - they've completed all the actions they needed to do. Logging out is a "meaningless" purely technical action, it's not part of their "to-do list".

Answer (score 8):

## It depends on the website / application

### They do

I can tell you that users DO log out, specially when there is a poor management of user accounts on a PC. I have seen people who share their PCs with their family, but do not have multiple users, so they have to keep logging out when they access the same systems (Say... same email provider), and when they want to protect their privacy (Say... a social network).

Also, I used to work (a long time ago) in a company that outsourced Customer Service, and we shared PCs, with the same user, it was an anarchy! We had to keep logging out every time we left the PC alone, because the next user could have a malicious intent.

### They Don't

There are certain services that I don't really care if someone gained access to because "I left my account logged in", such as Netflix, or YouTube. And the same family that I was talking about before doesn't log out from those either, they don't really care, because there is no sexting to be exposed from a social network's private messages, or because it is not a "personal" service like an email service.

### In Conclusion

I know that you have your own user in a PC, but think about those who don't.

It's all about the content of the application. Do you care if others look at it? What would happen if it is exposed? is it *THAT* popular so that it would be used by everyone sharing that PC?

Now. Please note this: it is a relatively small group of people. So it would be OK to be able to access to the log out from a menu quickly, say... 2-clicks away (do not uber-hide it), but it should not be super exposed.

Comment: Interesting thought on certain services such as Netflix. Specifically, Netflix is not the best example since other persons have a different taste and rate movies different - so the recommender algorithm doesn't work as well anymore.

Comment: Netflix has a "change users" button at the top of every page now, allowing you to swap sessions with the other profiles on your account. So if your spouse/sibling/child wants to use Netflix after you, they just need to choose their name from the profiles list with no password prompt.

Answer (score 4):

In my current role, the users who I interact with are mostly system administrators.  They generally do log out of applications (websites, web apps, desktop apps) when they are done using them.  If it's the middle of the day and they're simply stepping away from their workstation for a few minutes, then they will rely on locking their workstation.  If they're stepping away for longer than that, whether they logout is correlated to how long they're stepping away.  A short lunch is less likely to result in a logout, leaving at the end of the day is definitely a logout.

Answer (score 4):

Most users with college level age and experience, do not log out on their personal computer, and often do not log out on public computers.

I participate in many Facebook groups comprised of users with approximately a college level age and experience. Very frequently, a 3rd party will post on their wall something mildly funny and or embarrassing because the 3rd party came across a computer that was logged into the 'victims' Facebook account. This happens so frequently, that it has its own slang term, which is 'hacked'. Side note: this is an unfortunate slang term because it clouds the actually meaning of that word, and makes it seem more harmless.

Most kiosks and workstations at my college, to prevent that security issues with email and department logins, now use a per user login that resets all cache, cookies, and sessions on the computer whenever a user logs out. When using stable, or less public lab computers, many users treat it as an annoyance that the previous user did not log out of their sites, making the next user in line do extra 'work' to complete that step.

I have borrowed many a laptop in college and usually could have complete access to most of the owners sites.

This is a narrow sample size but I think illustrates common behavior. And if security concerns are treated this lightly for 'digital natives' (however much we dislike that term) we can anticipate that things are worse with those of less digital experience.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct to say it depends on their **risk**, and the **usability** of the site. I was a NetBank early adopter, and have used used it since before it was a browser application. I cannot share any hard facts with you, as I am an ex-CBA employee. In earlier years it was possible to have multiple concurrent logons in multiple tabs on the same browser. Thus it was easier to jump between "identities". Closing this functionality forces family members to logout and login explicitly between sessions (and so you should). Some do and some don't, **the ones that do tend not to have their family/housemates steal from them**, which frankly happens.

Since this change, a much higher percentage "do", although this is arguably the polite thing to do when relinquishing the keyboard.

(It certainly cuts down the total number of active sessions, which is always desirable from a performance point of view, sadly this is likely the driver for the timeout period, which will be shorter during peak loads).

Some people will consider "what's the worst that could happen" and behave accordingly, other people are exploit fodder.

These matters are over and above the perils of keystroke logging, password (and account) sharing and phishing forms.

Comment: CBA certainly aren't known for their security controls!